# How to retrieve only values of a single column in Crud Repository in Springboot from method Names without using @Query Annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

I need to retrieve distinct values of a particular column in CrudRepository in Springboot without using @Query annotation.

Answer (score 0):

A single value is not possible but you could use interface-based projections:

For example if you need only the name of a table:

```
interface NameOnly {
  String getName();
}

interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, UUID> {

  Collection<NameOnly> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

Read more here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections